# Expressing the solution of a differential equation in terms of the Bessel equation of order 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I found this question on a problem set for my Differential equations course:

> Show that the differential equation $y''+x^{-3/2}y=0$ has a non-trivial solution in terms of Bessel function $J_2(4x^{1/4})$.
>   [image]

My attempt at the solution:

I introduced the substitution $t = 4x^{1/4}$ into the given differential equation and tried to compare it with the Bessel equation of second order $t^2y''+ty'+(t^2-4)y=0$, but I was unable to think of the coefficient of $J_2$ in the solution in order to get the same equation.

Please provide alternate solutions or suggest ways to go through with my attempt

(Answer: The answeris $\sqrt x.J_2(x)$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the general parametrization $y(x)=x^au(bx^c)$ and insert, 
\begin{align}
y'(x)&=x^{a-1}(au(bx^c)+bcx^cu'(bx^c))\\[.5em]
-x^{a-3/2}u(bx^c)=y''(x)&=(a-1)x^{a-2}\Bigl(au(bx^c)+bcx^cu'(bx^c)\Bigr)
\\&~~~+x^{a-1}\Bigl((a+c)bcx^{c-1}u'(bx^c)+b^2c^2x^{2c-1}u''(bx^c)\Bigr)
\\[.5em]
-x^{1/2}u(bx^c)&=a(a-1)u(bx^c)+(2a+c-1)bcx^cu'(bx^c)+b^2c^2x^{2c}u''(bx^c)
\end{align}

To get the form of the Bessel equation one needs $c=\frac14$ to satisfy equality of degrees in $x^{1/2}\sim x^{2c}$. Thus inserting with $t=bx^{1/4}$
$$
t^2u''(t)+4(2a-3/4)tu'(t)+16[b^{-2}t^2+a(a-1)]u(t)=0
$$ 
leading to $b=4$, $8a-3=1\implies a=1/2$,
so that
$$y(x)=x^{1/2}u(4x^{1/4})~~\text{ and }~~
t^2u(t)+tu(t)+[t^2-4]u(t)=0.
$$ 
As was given in the claim.